# How to have a paid and free version of iOS app share FB App ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I have a free and a paid version of the same iPhone app. I would like for them to share a Facebook App ID since they are essentially the same app. I thought I could accomplish this by using this method from the Facebook class.

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions localAppId:(NSString *)localAppId
```

However, login always fails for one of the apps (in my case the free version) and it would seem that the reason is that the Facebook app created in the web interface asks for an App Bundle ID and App Store ID. Obviously the free version and paid version of my apps cannot have the same bundle id or app id so how can I make this work?

The docs in Facebook.m suggest that it is possible with the authorize method I mention above:

```
/*
 * ...
 * @param localAppId
 *            This is useful if your have multiple iOS applications that
 *            share a single Facebook application id (for example, if you
 *            have a free and a paid version on the same app) and you want
 *            to use SSO with both apps. 
 * ...
 */
```

Thanks.
- Alex

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work. Each app must have different url schemes (since that is how Facebook redirects back to your app).

Example url schemes you must support:
(Your facebook app id: "fb123456789")

**Without setting localAppId:** "fb123456789" *(localAppId = nil)*

**Free app url scheme:** "fb123456789lite" *(localAppId = "lite")*

**Paid app url scheme:** "fb123456789pro" *(localAppId = "pro")*

From the comments:

> localAppId is a string of lowercase letters that is appended to the
>   base URL scheme used for SSO. For example, if your facebook ID is
>   "350685531728" and you set localAppId to "abcd", the Facebook app will
>   expect your application to bind to the following URL scheme:
>   "fb350685531728abcd".

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have exactly what you describe but I don't think that is the problem. On the web side of things at this URL: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/FBID/summary there is a field for Bundle ID and App Store ID under the Mobile Native Section. The comment next to Bundle ID says "For security reasons, we check the bundle id when we callback your app". But the comments in the API of Facebook.m seem to contradict this.

Comment: You don't need to put anything in the web interface. When you want to authorize facebook, call [_facebook authorize:_permissions localAppId:@"lite"]; or [_facebook authorize:_permissions localAppId:@"pro"];

Comment: Really I can leave all that stuff blank? I will try that. Should I change it to a web app instead of a native mobile app?

Comment: Well I'd certainly fill everything in before going onto the store, but none of that is required for functionality. Everything works for me with nothing filled in. All you need is to have your iOS app accept the correct URL scheme(s) and call authorize:. Also, if you don't see the section that I quoted above, you should check to see if there is a newer FB SDK on GitHub. There might also be a disclaimer about this only working with the Facebook v3.4.1+ iOS App.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that worked. For anyone else looking at this. The key is to mark your App Type as "Web" instead of "Native/Desktop" when you are filling out your app info on the Facebook create app pages. When you are Native/Desktop app it requires the Bundle ID and checks against that in the callback. If you are web app it ignores it. I am a little worried FB might "fix" this in the future and it will stop working but I will cross that bridge when I come to it.

Comment: Hey guys. Seems not working anymore. If I leave the Bundle ID empty when connecting to FB in my app it gives a warning that Bundle ID was not input. So how to solve for single FB app (with suffix) but 2 Bundle IDs of 2 free/pro iOS app?

Comment: Hey guys, new FB application settings page Web setting don't have the suffix field anymore. So we're left to put as Native Apps. Anybody knows how to do this?