# Facebook URL Schemes for both Free and Paid Apps

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have set up the URL scheme suffix on Facebook to have a "paid" and "free" version of my app. Now, I have submitted a paid and free version of my App on the App Store using 2 different bundle identifiers: `com.mycompany.myapppaid` and `com.mycompany.myappfree`. I have used the correct URL type for each app (fbMYFACEBOOKIDpaid, and fbMYFACEBOOKIDfree).

According to the Facebook app page, there is only a single spot for a single bundle identifier, how does Facebook differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [a previous question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368656/314042):

Mark your app as "Web".

Bundle ID is not necessary.

**EDITED FOR NEW VERSION OF FACEBOOK IOS SDK:**

```
- (id)initWithAppId:(NSString *)appId
    urlSchemeSuffix:(NSString *)urlSchemeSuffix
        andDelegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate;
```

When you initialize the Facebook object, you need to initialize it with the appropriate "paid" or "free" suffix.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Call `- (void)authorize:localAppId:` accordingly

> The key is to mark your App Type as "Web" instead of "Native/Desktop"
> when you are filling out your app info on the Facebook create app
> pages. When you are Native/Desktop app it requires the Bundle ID and
> checks against that in the callback. If you are web app it ignores it.
>
> You don't need to put anything in the web interface. When you want to
> authorize facebook, call [_facebook authorize:_permissions
> localAppId:@"free"]; or [_facebook authorize:_permissions
> localAppId:@"paid"];

Comment: I know this answer was valid back then, but it seems like the new FB iOS SDK does not have the method: authorize:localAppId. Instead, only authorize:.

Comment: +1 Awesome Thanks. I was about to post it myself as I just found the solution :)

Comment: This worked for me too.  I also added both bundle id's to the facebook page.  Example 'com.company.myapp' and 'com.company.myappfree'